# Too many actual parameters for my own class?

Tags: delphi

I've started working with OOP today in Delphi. I've made a simple 'Box' with a function that returns the volume when the user enters the length, breadth and height.

Here's my class:

```
unit clsBox;
interface
uses
  SysUtils;
  Type
  TBox = class(TObject)
  private
  fL, fB, fH : Integer;
  constructor Create (a, b, c : Integer);
  function getVolume : Integer;
  public
  end;
implementation
{ TBox }
constructor TBox.Create(a, b, c: Integer);
begin
  a := fL;
  b := fB;
  c := fH;
end;

function TBox.getVolume: Integer;
begin
  Result := fL*fb*fh;
end;

end.
```

I have also created the variable for the box in the private section of the original unit

```
myBox : TBox;
```

But when I try this:

```
procedure TForm1.btnGetVolumeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  l,b,h : Integer;
begin
  l := StrToInt(edtLegth.Text);
  b := StrToInt(edtBreadth.Text);
  h := StrToInt(edtHeight.Text);
  myBox := TBox.Create(l,b,h); //<---- here
end;
```

It gives me an error saying `Too many actual parameteres`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor is private and so cannot be seen from the other unit. From the other unit, the parameterless constructor declared in `TObject` can be seen and that is what the compiler assumes you are calling.

Make your constructor public.

You'll have the same problem when you want to call `getVolume`. Perhaps that's intended to be used as a property getter.

Your constructor also performs its initialization incorrectly. All three assignment statements are incorrect and need to have their operands reversed.

The names of the constructor parameters are not informative. How can the reader deduce their use from the names a, b and c?

Comment: And the same problem with getVolume

Comment: @AidanQuinn And change `a := fL;...` to `fL := a;...` in the constuctor's body.

Comment: @Abelisto Oh yes, of course! I need to get my eyes tested. I'm watching 240p videos our Department of Education (South Africa) gave us, very blurry

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Im just working through the tutorial I have, I agree, they are bad and probably why I'm confused as well

Comment: What tutorial are you using, Aidan? We need to know not to recommend it to others.

Comment: @RobKennedy Last year they decided to change the curriculum for IT, so I could get rid of my horrible text book that I had. They gave us a CD with a bunch of fundamentals for Delphi starting with string handling, arrays, procedures and functions, Database programming and OOP. We got a video tutorial for each subject, but very low quality. And I highly doubt others will find these tutorials, thank goodness xD  **Edit** I don't think South Africa has developed the best programmers of today hey?